# Discard last line if is uncompleted

Tags: c, string

If I have a file loaded in a buffer, how can I discard the last line if it is uncompleted (does not end with `"\n"`)

I think of poppulating the buffer using [getline()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) line by line until the buffer is full.

**There is a simpler way to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... have a file loaded in a buffer

Find the last `'\n'`:

```
char *end = strrchr(buffer, '\n');
// If \n found 
if (end) {
  // Insure next char is the null character
  *(end + 1) = '\0';
  }
} else {
  buffer[0] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum line length then [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) in a loop is a good alternative. It also have the whole "append newline if it's there" thing, so you can easily check if the line you just read had a newline or not.

Otherwise just bulk-read into the buffer using [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread), and when you have read the last part of the file check if the last character is a newline or not. If not, then search for the last newline ([`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) is a good function for this) and terminate the buffer there.